# Is there a better expression to 'turning point' in the paragraph below?

Tags: expression-choice

Considering the efforts undertaken so far in sampling traditional molecular markers for the family Cactaceae, and that new sequencing technologies have become increasingly accessible, and are now starting to be used in the study of cacti, we believe that this is the appropriate moment for a review of the current knowledge achieved using molecular markers up to this **turning point**.

Comment: Welcome! Can you edit to say exactly *what* concerns you about the phrase? Note that "up to this point" is an existing phrase, and so is "turning point." There's no harm in omitting "turning," but if you do want to emphasize this point as one of change, it's reasonable to combine the two phrases as shown.

Comment: I would put "turning point" first:  "....we believe  that a turning point has been reached and that this is the appropriate moment for a review of current knowledge achieved using molecular markers [up to now]." I'm not sure the "up to now" adds much, especially with "current."

Comment: You could look up *milestone* and see if it fits your idea better than *turning point.*

Comment: I'm certain it's not the word you want, as its main meaning negative, but *crisis* can have a specific meaning of a turning point in a literary plot. Perhaps "pivotal moment" might serve your purposes. But please edit to explain more about what you're going for, and you'll get more focused answers.

Comment: You should remove these commas: *Cactaceae,* and *accessible,*. And then consider breaking the whole sentence into smaller ones.

Comment: I think it reads just fine without "up to this turning point"

Comment: You might end it *... achieved using those traditional markers.*.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. They helped me a lot to write a more harmonic sentence. Here is the reviewed sentence:  Considering the efforts undertaken so far in sampling traditional molecular markers for the family Cactaceae, and that the increasing accessibility to new sequencing technologies (Dijk et al. 2014; Wetterstrand, 2021) has been fostered genomic sampling in Cactaceae, we believe that a turning point has been reached and that this is the appropriate moment for a review of current knowledge achieved using those molecular markers

Comment: Better!  But I'd encourage you to visit your institution's Writing Center because you'll get better support there than here for the writing process.  Happy writing!